# How can I make this code more 'functional programming' style in Ramda.js / lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash, ramda.js

I have this bit of code:

```
var fn = function(fn, name) {
   this.commands.add(name, fn);
}.bind(this);

_.mapObjIndexed(fn, this.commandList);
```

I feel like there's a way to improve this bit of code and make it just one line. I tried many different ways, but I'm new to `ramda.js` and I might be missing some function, that would make this easier and simpler.

Comment: You can always make it one line by concatenating them all together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be looking for the [`flip` function](https://lodash.com/docs#flip) / [`flip` function](http://ramdajs.com/0.20.1/docs/#flip):

```
_.mapObjIndexed(_.flip(this.commands.add), this.commandList);
```

If a `.bind(this.commands)` for the `add` function is necessary, you can shorten that using `_.bindKey(this.commands, "add")`.

If the flipping doesn't work correctly because of the number of arguments, you might needt to throw in [`_.ary(…, 2)`](https://lodash.com/docs#ary) or [`_.binary(…)`](http://ramdajs.com/0.20.1/docs/#binary).

Comment: Thank you. this works perfectly: `_.mapObjIndexed(_.flip(_.bind(this.commands.add, this)), this.commandList)`

Comment: @SuchMuchCode: All Ramda, I guess? Btw I don't think you need the `bind` when you're binding to `this` instead of to `this.commands`.

Comment: My bad, I am actually binding to `this.commands`. I mistyped above. And yes, if not this, I wouldn't need to use bind. :)